# how to send a parameter an activity class to a normal class?

Tags: android

in my project i am using voice recognition. i want to take the result of that class and pass it another class. But because this class is not an activity class, i cant use intent. the codes i use in voice recognition are like that:

protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
    {

```
     if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK){
         ArrayList<String> matches = new ArrayList<String>();
    matches = data.getStringArrayListExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);


    if(matches.size()>0)  {
         result = matches.get(0);}}
```

I want to take that result and use another class which is not an activity class. So please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can declare you ArrayList as a static one like this,

```
public static ArrayList<String> array = new ArrayList<String>();
```

By doing this you can access your ArrayList from anywhere by

```
activity_name.array;
```

where activity_name is the activity or class in which you declare the static ArrayList

Comment: i want to reach that array from another class in which it is not declared. i have another class called upload. it is not an activity class. there is a function " uploadmetadata.setTitle(result) " in that class. i want the result in voicerecognition class to use in that function.

Comment: Yes, you can declare your result variable as public static and can access it from anywhere.

Comment: If you have further query come to casual chat room.

Answer (score 0):

You need to save the data. For this you can use `SQlite, SharedPreference or static variable`..

Answer (score 0):

you can define the setters/getters inside that normal class. Later on, retrieve the value by using that setter method of that class through object.

Comment: i dont know how to use exactly. I want to use the result like that uploadmetadata.setTitle(result). but this function in another class that i mentioned